# private variables resetting between methods c#

Tags: c#, scope

This is probably the biggest noob question ever but I'm confused as to why my private variables, when they are set in one method, gets reset in another. I have something like this in my code:

```
namespace Project.Messages
{
public partial class Inbox : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private static int selectedIndex;
    private static string messageIDString;
    private static int messageID; 

    //select message to view
    protected void viewMessage(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
            //get index
            selectedIndex = MsgInbox.SelectedIndex;
            if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out selectedIndex))
            {
                //get selected dataKey, convert to a int
                messageIDString = MsgInbox.DataKeys[selectedIndex].Value.ToString();
                messageID = Convert.ToInt16(messageIDString);
            }
     }

    //select message to delete
    protected void delBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Messages WHERE MessageID =    @param1", conn);
        conn.Open();

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", messageID);
    }
```

So if I click a message, messageID will be set and the message will be displayed. When I click to delete message after that though, it looks like the variable is resetting/is not the same value as previously set. Do I need to use a static variable or something to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: No it doesn't have to be static if it's used within the class.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838426/variable-initialized-in-class-loses-its-previous-value-with-the-page-loading

Comment: I think you're confused about `ASP.NET`, the page life cycle and how data is persisted upon postbacks. You need to learn a little more about ASP.NET and understand that your page object is created, run and then dumped on each page request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the behaviour. When there is postback, all variables are reset and reassigned. You can use session or viewstate or store the value in a control on the page which is already part of the viewstate e.g. in an hidden field

```
public int messageID
{
   get 
   { 
      int retVal = 0;
      if(ViewState["messageID"] != null)
         Int32.TryParse(ViewState["messageID"].ToString(), out retVal); 

      return retVal;
   }
   set { ViewState["messageID"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This works pretty well! Except I didn't use int32.TryParse, it gave me a params error. I just did the Convert.ToInt16. Thanks again!

Comment: In my case, the page wasn't being reloaded, a variable was set in one method (a databound select method), then stepping through, the very next press of F10, when responding to the OnDataBound event, the variable had been reset. But yeah, using Session seems to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of ASP.NET, not C#. You need to save your variables in viewstate. See: [variable initialized in class loses its previous value with the page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838426/variable-initialized-in-class-loses-its-previous-value-with-the-page-loading)

Comment: Thanks. Like I said, noob question. :p

Answer (score 1):

It is because the web is stateless. Here are some methods for passing data between pages.

ASP.net MVC:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx

ASP.net Webforms
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=VS.100).aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Session object to store information that you need between requests.
Eg: `Session["messageIdString"]=value`

For more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have used quite a few Session variables in this program. All I have gotten through my quick googling of the difference of Session and ViewState variables is that Session you can use between web pages, while ViewState is just for 1 page. So I thought ViewState might be better? Not positive.