# Incrementing an int++ doesn't go past 1

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have 3 ints that are supposed to increment when the button is clicked, and then their values are turned to strings and updated on a cooresponding label, but they never increment past 1.

```
 public partial class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Random rd = new Random();
    int oneint = 0;
    int twoint = 0;
    int threeint = 0;


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rn = rd.Next(1, 1000);

        if (rn > 1 && rn < 50)
        {
            Label1.Text = "3";
            threeint++;
            threelbl.Text = threeint.ToString();
        }

        if (rn > 50 && rn < 500)
        {
            Label1.Text = "2";
            twoint++;
            twolbl.Text = twoint.ToString();
        }

        if (rn > 500 && rn < 1000)
        {
            Label1.Text = "1";
            oneint++;
            onelbl.Text = oneint.ToString();
        }

    }
```

This is for an ASP.NET webforms webpage. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `are supposed to increment when the button is clicked` and only when RN is in some range

Comment: Every time you load the page your ints are initialized to zero.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838426/variable-initialized-in-class-loses-its-previous-value-with-the-page-loading

Comment: Each time you perform an action that posts back to the server it creates a new instance of the page and everything gets reset. The article provides some suggestions you could use to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you initialize the variables as global variables they will still reset to zero unless they are persisted somehow.

There are a few ways to do that.

- You could create `<asp:hidden runat="server">` elements and store the values in those. That's probably the easiest.
- You could store the values in ViewState during the `PreRender` event and retrieve them again in the `Load` event.

In both cases that ensures that the values are output to the page, which means that they'll be sent back to the server with any postback event. For simplicity I'd just use the hidden form elements. But if there's any type of complex data then I

- create a class containing the values, and mark it as serializable
- put that class in a global variable
- restore the variable from ViewState with in the `Load` event
- save it in the `PreRender` event.

  ```
  public partial class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      Random rd = new Random();
      private PageState _pageState;

      protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
      {
          _pageState = ViewState["pageState"] as PageState ?? new PageState();
      }

      protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          ViewState["pageState"] = _pageState;
      }

      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          int rn = rd.Next(1, 1000);

          if (rn > 1 && rn < 50)
          {
              Label1.Text = "3";
              _pageState.threeint++;
              threelbl.Text = _pageState.threeint.ToString();
          }

          if (rn > 50 && rn < 500)
          {
              Label1.Text = "2";
              _pageState.twoint++;
              twolbl.Text = _pageState.twoint.ToString();
          }

          if (rn > 500 && rn < 1000)
          {
              Label1.Text = "1";
              _pageState.oneint++;
              onelbl.Text = _pageState.oneint.ToString();
          }
      }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class PageState
  {
      public int oneint { get; set; }
      public int twoint { get; set; }
      public int threeint { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As is, you are initializing the variables to zero each time the page is loaded. So after the first increment, it will go back to zero, explaining why it never increments past 1. Refer to ScottHannen's answer, as it is much more apt in explaining on how to work around this.

Comment: Think of a webform as a class that is instantiated every time there is a request for that page. It doesn't "know" anything about previous requests. It doesn't save an instance of that page between requests. That's why there's viewstate. Information about the current state is written to the page. When the user does a postback they send all of that data back to the page so that it can "remember" what the state was. Server controls are saved to viewstate by default but variables aren't. If you want to persist them you have to do it yourself.

Comment: You are completely right, my mistake. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep value of all three int fields accross post back, you can retain ot by view state or session or hidden field which you will get in post back, or also can be in query string.