# Access variables after initialization in page load ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have this webform:

```
public class web1{
    private string target = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventsArgs e){
        target = "something";
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //use target variable here
    }
}
```

When I click the button which triggers `btnSubmit_Click()` the `target` variable gets reset to `string.Empty` because of `private string target = string.Empty`.

Currently I'm assigning the new value to a `Session` and clearing it after the button click, but was wondering if there was a way of avoiding `Session`.

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: _"but was wondering if there was a way of avoiding `Session`."_ - well, there's always `ViewState` (lol).

Comment: @Dai well, legacy work stuff, is it doable with just a `string` variable?

Comment: So anyway, your code _should_ work as-is - but I think what you're _really_ doing is wanting to use `target` between `POST`/PostBack requests?

Comment: @Dai yeah pretty much

Comment: In which case using `Session` is probably appropriate - but it does suggest _something wrong_ with your application's design (besides the fact you're still using WebForms...) because the web is meant to be stateless.

Comment: @Dai Found this answer from another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838473/19342899

Also, I'm quitting in two days, so no more webforms :D

Comment: I wish you Godspeed, sir!

Comment: yes, web is supposed to be stateless, but now we have blazer server, and it more of a webforms type of setup, and even more so it keeps a 100% active signalR connection's active and running, and along with your code variables intact. so much for the concept of stateless then, right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typcial would work:

private string target = string.Empty;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventsArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        target = "something";
        ViewState["target"] = target;
    }
    else
        target = (string)ViewState["target"]; 
}
```

Now any button click, event code, or whatever is free to use target.